# CefSharp Run .net task from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, task, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am using cefsharp.Wpf and I need to run 2 commands togheter.

This is the object I am binding to my javascript

```
public class CefSharpCommonObject
{
    public dynamic Start()
    {
        var response = dummyProc.Start();

        return new
        {
            response.IsSuccess
        };
    }

    public dynamic Stop()
    {
        var response = dummyProc.Stop();

        return new
        {
            response.IsSuccess
        };
    }
}
```

Like the following:

```
cefBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("jsCommunicator", new CefSharpCommonObject(), true);
```

I call the start method using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (async () => {
        await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("jsCommunicator", "jsTest");

        jsCommunicator.start().then(() => {}, () => {});

        setTimeout(jsCommunicator.stop, 5000);
    })();
</script>
```

The start method uses a while loop that checks something and then sleeps for 1 second and I fear it may be blocking the UI thread because the stop method isn't being called. Only after the start method auto exits after like 30 seconds.

Is there a way I can make the start method a task so I can run it in another thread and still get the return value after it stops?

Comment: You can use a call back see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/63/CefSharp.Example/BoundObject.cs#L59

Comment: Support for returning `Task<T>` has been added in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2758